# ASP.NET Core: Kestrel web server and background Task hosted on single console process

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, host, kestrel-http-server

Is this a bad idea to use same console app instance as Kestrel web server self-host and host process for some background work?

```
public class Program
    {
        private static IServiceRoot _root;

        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            _root = new HostContainer().Resolve<IServiceRoot>();

            // Starting some background work
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await _root.PerformWorkAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }).DoNotAwait();

            // Starting web server
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }


        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddSingleton<IServiceRoot>(_root);
                }).Build();
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
Background work is a heavy CPU/IO bound task that should run continiously (gets data from Web, stores in DB), I just use ASP.NET Core as Web API to control it's status over HTTP. Looks like the tail wags the dog in this case. Is there more preferable approaches here? (I use Azure). Should I move IHostedService I've implemented to WebJob?

Comment: Yes, it's a bad idea, but not in principle, just in how you're doing it. In ASP.NET Core 2.0, you should use `IHostedService` (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/)

Comment: This looks a lot like something that might be better off as a scheduled task or service. Additionally, this looks like a task you want to be run continuously. If you end up using IIS as a reverse proxy with Kestrel, then this task flat-out won't run until someone visits your site. With `IHostedService`, you are also at the mercy of a shutdown event. Still, without knowing more about your requirements, `IHostedService` is definitely a better approach than what you currently have.

Comment: @CalC, you're right, please look at the update

Comment: @AsValeO: I think using a WebJob might be a more salable approach. However, I think the availability of continuous/"always-on" functionality for WebJobs may depend on he pricing tier of your website